# Problem with multiple str_replace

Tags: php, string, replace

I have 2 linked files and I need to replace 2 things.
only the first one works the other still has the placeholder.

FILE 1

```
ob_start() ;

//buffers and gets title and meta
echo "<title>";
$gettitle="##pagetitle##";
echo $gettitle;
echo "</title>";

echo "<META NAME=\"Description\" CONTENT=\"";
$getmeta="##metacontent##";
echo $getmeta;
echo "\">";
```

FILE 2

```
$pagetitle = "Reviews and Tutorials" ;
  str_replace("##pagetitle##", $pagetitle, $gettitle) ;
$metacontent = "Reviews and Tutorials from Socal Mods. Discover something new!" ;
  str_replace("##metacontent##", $metacontent, $getmeta) ;
ob_clean;
```

So in the resulting page the title works, but it just prints ##metacontent##.

thanks in advance

Ive tried screwing around with different ob_ controls but cant get it to work.

Comment: We don't see how you retrieve the ob contents, please add those fragments to the code. It may be that you unnecessarily `ob_clean` after first replacement.

Comment: the ob_clean after the first one was an accident.

what do you mean ob contents, thats all the relevant code I have

Comment: What I mean is - shouldn't you be retrieving contents of the output buffer in order to manipulate them? In file 2
`$gettitle = ob_get_contents();`
`$getmeta = ob_get_contents();`
Or how do you get values in these vars? are you including one file into another in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first ob_clean. It would work.

Comment: I already did, it was never in the code, was an accident still nothing